# Doesn't the sublimation rate on glaciers depend on the (specific) latent heat of sublimation of water ice?

Tags: glaciology, thermodynamics

On p. 6 of this article:

[Bliss, A.K., Cuffey, K.M., Kavanaugh, J.L., 2011. Sublimation and surface energy budget of Taylor Glacier, Antarctica. Journal of Glaciology 57, 684–696.](http://www.igsoc.org:8080/journal/57/204/t10J220.pdf)

There is an expression for sublimation rate as a function of latent heat flux $L$ and (specific) latent heat of sublimation (of water ice) $\lambda$.

[image]

But then $L$ itself is given as a function of the latent heat of sublimation ($\lambda$):

[image]

So... doesn't $\lambda$ cancel out!? This would imply that the latent heat of sublimation doesn't matter at all here, which I guess is possible since it's a kinetically controlled process.